# Coding a string length function using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-length

I'm in a beginner CS class learning C and we were tasked with coding a function to find string length using only string pointers. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strlength(char* str);

int main() {
    char *str;
    int comp;

    printf("Please enter the string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    printf("The length of the string is: %d\n", strlength(str));
    return 0;
}

int strlength(char *str) {
    int length = 0;

    while(*str != '\0') {
        length++;
        str++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

I'm not really sure where I'm getting a segmentation fault. I've tried making a second pointer in the strlength function that equals str and incrementing that, but that also gives me a segmentation fault. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO!  The best thing to do is to learn to use the debugger -- it can show you a "call stack" or "stack trace" and it can stop on seg faults and exceptions and show you the state of the program.

Comment: `char *str;` creates an uninitialized pointer pointing to some unknown location in memory that is probably not allocated for your program, so trying to stick a string into that location causes a segfault. You need to actually allocate some memory and make `str` point to the memory you allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *str;
int comp;

printf("Please enter the string: ");
scanf("%s", str);
```

You should allocate memory in heap ( with malloc ) for `*str` before scanf. If you dont want to use malloc change it to char[number] so it can allocate memory in stack instead of heap

Comment: So we haven't been taught about malloc yet so I don't think we're allowed to do that, but I did consider the other way. I just can't figure out how to initialize the character array with a size without having the string that I'm putting it in yet... How would I go about this?

Comment: Its simple. Assume there is a certain limit of characters which you can type in. I.e. 1000 and initialize variable with such size